# MongoDb Atlas Data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest

I am trying to store my node rest api data to mongodb atlas. But getting insertion errors. I have even added the 'user' with Read and Write permissions but still no solution. Here is the error :

```
   {
    "error": {
        "name": "MongoError",
        "message": "user is not allowed to do action [insert] on [test.products]",
        "ok": 0,
        "errmsg": "user is not allowed to do action [insert] on [test.products]",
        "code": 8000,
        "codeName": "AtlasError"
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51340617/storing-data-to-mongodb-atlas

Comment: Check whether the user' permission is for database `test` and collection `products`. Pease post the permission as well to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved a similar issue by changing the connection method from **mongodb+srv://** to **mongodb://**.

The **mongodb://** connection string can be found be selecting an earlier version of the Node.js driver in the MongoDb Atlas *choose a connection method* section. I selected *v2.2.12 or later*.